# OpenGL ES screen to world coordinate

Tags: opengl, iphone, ios, opengl-es

I am currently attempting to convert my screen coordinates to world coordinates, to be able to interact with objects. I am using glm and unProject to try and achieve this, so far this is my code:

```
glm::vec4 viewPort = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);
glm::mat4 tmpView = sceneCamera->updateView();
glm::mat4 tmpProj = sceneCamera->updateProjection();
glm::vec3 screenPos = glm::vec3(touchPosition.x, height - touchPosition.y - 1.0f, 1.0f);
glm::vec3 worldPos = glm::unProject(screenPos, tmpView, tmpProj, viewport);

Renderer->SceneObjects[120]->translateX(worldPos.x);
Renderer->SceneObjects[120]->translateY(worldPos.y);
```

I am trying to get a sprite to equal the position where I tap.
The issues is that the further I click going down the screen, the further the sprite overshoots, and the same horizontally. So if I click 2/3 the way down the screen, the sprite will overshoot the bottom of the screen.

[image: Image of sprite to be moved]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math looks sound, so it's hard to say for sure, but based on the description of your bug I think your touch coordinates are in a different range from your viewport.

If your pixel locations are in a range of x:[0,800), y:[0,600), but your touch coordinates are in x:[0,1024), y:[0,768), you would see a scaling effect where the farther you tap away from the origin, the farther the sprite overshoots its intended target.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what is going on. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I realised that I am using view.drawableWidth and view.drawableHeight which is returning 320x320, not 1024x768...

Comment: Thought so. Did you manage to get it sorted out? All you should need to do is scale your touch coordinates to match your viewport size.

Comment: It is sorted now, thanks Daniel. The devil is always in the details as they say.